# NSURLRequest indirect link get file name

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest

I am asynchronously downloading image files with NSURLRequest.
Paths to files are indirect. After downloading a file, is there an easy way to get the final path (filename)?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURL has two methods:

```
absoluteString
absoluteURL
```

These will give you the full path in URL or string form.

These methods rely on the baseURL property of the NSURL to be set so they can construct the full path, but if you downloaded the file I assume that the baseURL must have been correctly set, otherwise it couldn't have worked.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser but thats not what I need - lets say the url is http://192.168.1.1/image - this path redirects to a image somewhere else. I would like to get that path (the image downloads correctly). Mentioned NSURL methods will return the relative url.

Comment: Sorry, "indirect" was ambiguous. I don't know for sure but you may be able to get that URL from the NSURLResponse object that comes back after you make a request, depending on exactly how you are loading your image.

Comment: Ahh yes indeed!  This gives me what I need:

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"%@",response.suggestedFilename);
}`

Thanks for the hint!